Use latest data in training a timeseries model
I am training a global timeseries deep learning model.
I have split the data for training, validation(to select the best hyperparameters), and test(to test on out of sample data).
There are only 3 data points per year and the train, val and test data over the years are shown below.

The breakdown of the training data is shown below where we use 2 years of data and test on the 3rd year. I use a fixed rolling window to create training samples as shown which is similar to what Wayne has mentioned.

With this structure, the model has visibility only upto 2021 of training data and doesn't include the latest 2 years of data in training. Is there a way to include all the data upto 2023? I can create a new model which uses the existing model's hyperparameters and include all the data, upto 2023, to retrain the new model. Is this a good idea?

Did you check https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_learning
